# How to get the UITextField's delegates events while subclassing it, without losing the delegation if the user of it set itself as the delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield, subclassing

For simplicity, let's say I want to create a custom `UITextField` and I want to add a simple behaviour to it; Which is, if the textfield becomes the first responder, the background color would be changed to green.

To do so, in my custom class I have to set the class as the delegate to receive the event of becoming first responder. But the thing is that if the user of this custom textfield set itself as the delegate the events are not sent to the custom textfield(Since only one object can be the delegate of another object)

I can manually forward all the events, but I'm looking for a cleaner and more scalable solution.

Here's a sketch of the situation:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyTextField: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
}
```

but if the user of `MyTextField` do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: MyTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

the behaviour won't work; because the delegation relationship to MyTextField is gone.

**NOTE**: I'm not only interested in becoming first responder problem, rather it's about using any methods of the delegate, with capability of the user of my custom UITextField setting itself as the delegate, at the same time.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, most delegation is restricted to a single object as the delegate.

Since a text field is a responder, you should be able to override `func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool` to change the color, while letting the user of the object handle the delegation as it expects.

UIResponder docs: "Subclasses can override this method to update state or perform some action such as highlighting the selection."

Comment: @philip Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I used this example just for simplicity; and my question is not only for becoming first responder; I'm more interested in knowing how can I subclass a UIKit class and using the delegate in my custom class without losing the delegation connection after a user of my custom UIKit class set itself as the delegate.

Comment: @philip By the way, is there any delegation that is not restricted to only one object?

Comment: Within the SDK, I'm not sure.  We've done it in-house for cases where we want to support multiple callbacks but with more structure (i.e. a protocol) than KVO or notifications provide.